# Is this a pastiche of a particular painting or photograph?

Tags: russia, art

The children's book *Zen Ghosts* by Jon J. Muth depicts a Halloween in suburban America, with several unexplained figures trick-or-treating in the background.  Among them are these two children:

[image: Two trick-or-treating children. On left, a boy dressed in black tie formal wear with medals and ribbons on his chest. On right, a child dressed in what appears to be a traditional Russian costume of high quality.]

This image seems familiar to me.  I thought at first that it might be a pastiche of either a depiction of Romanov children or one of [Produkin-Gorsky's](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sergey_Prokudin-Gorsky) photographs.  But a Google image search came up dry.  I also checked for images of Leo Tolstoy's children, because Muth had previously adapted "The Three Questions" to a children's book, but I found only photos of them in their adulthood.

Is this based on a historic painting or photograph?  Or is it just from Muth's imagination?

Comment: Does the actual illustration in the book appear to be a photograph, or a painting? I ask because details can become blurry when a small section of a photograph is enlarged. Is the illustrator Muth or someone else?

Comment: @Spencer It's painted. Muth is both the author and the illustrator.

Comment: Thanks. Please edit your question to work that information in.

Comment: Also, since the author is still alive, you might get a definitive answer by asking him directly.